# Error : Merging checkpoint with graph to get Frozen Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow from source in my machine (cpu machine) without cuda support, 
so I would like to convert a sample tensorflow model to tflite, but when I want to merge checkpoint with .pg graph I found the following error :

**Command line :**

```
~/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools$** python freeze_graph.py --input_graph=/home/hamza/object_detection/saved_model1/frozen_inference_graph.pb --input_checkpoint=~/object_detection/saved_model1/model.ckpt --input_binary=true --output_graph=~/object_detection/saved_model1/frozen_graph.pb  --output_node_names=ObjectRes
```

---

**Output error :**

```html
2018-05-22 09:18:32.403770: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "freeze_graph.py", line 382, in <module>
    run_main()
  File "freeze_graph.py", line 379, in run_main
    app.run(main=my_main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "freeze_graph.py", line 378, in <lambda>
    my_main = lambda unused_args: main(unused_args, flags)
  File "freeze_graph.py", line 272, in main
    flags.saved_model_tags, checkpoint_version)
  File "freeze_graph.py", line 254, in freeze_graph
    checkpoint_version=checkpoint_version)
  File "freeze_graph.py", line 128, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos
    var_list=var_list, write_version=checkpoint_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1218, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1227, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1263, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 729, in _build_internal
    saveables = self._ValidateAndSliceInputs(names_to_saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 632, in _ValidateAndSliceInputs
    variable)
TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases:0", shape=(12,), dtype=float32)
```

Please Could you help me to solve this problem,

Best Regards,

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow, and which version of `freeze_graph.py`?

Comment: I have tensorflow version 1.4.1, the freeze_graph included into tensorflow from source built with bazel 0.10.0

Comment: Oh I see. The graph is already frozen, so there are no variables in the graph to replace. You'll need to start with the non-frozen graph.

Comment: Please how I can start with non-frozen graph,
Thank you very much,